# Sympy: Using logical operators on relationals

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Is this possible? What I want to do is something like this: `sympify('2>1 | 2<1')`

I pretty much only need 'or' and 'and'. I also tried doing `sympify('2>1') | sympify('2<1')`. Ideally I would want to just be able to send in a string with relations and logical operators to a function and have it return true or false. (i.e. `'(2>1 | 2<1) & 3==3'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in Python/SymPy: you need to surround the inequalities with parentheses otherwise `1 | 2` is evaluated first and an error is raised by SymPy. You can write:

```
>>> sympify('(2>1) | (2<1)')
True # SymPy bool
```

Of course, you don't really need SymPy's power for logical expressions just involving `&` and `|`. Python's `bool` type supports the operators although you still need parentheses to ensure the correct result:

```
>>> (2>1) | (2<1)
True # Python bool
```

Comment: Thanks! bool doesn't handle strings though, and i'm doing it on user input so I don't really know how many inequalities will be in a string. I figured it would be easier to use sympy than parsing the strings myself.